# How to connect to an FTP server from an existing connection to Unix server?

Tags: java, unix, ssh, ftp, jsch

Currently I am using [Reflection for Unix and OpenVMS](http://support.attachmate.com/techdocs/2344.html). I connect to a Unix server. Once connected, I establish a new FTP connection to the target server. Here is how the console window look like:

```
login: xxx 
Password : xxx 
// Now I'm connected to UNIX
// Next I am connecting to that FTP 
ftpLogin@hostName :/whatever/.../ $ ftp someftp.example.com 
Conencted 
Name: myLogin 
Password: 
XXX 
Login OK
```

---

I tried to replicate the same steps programmatically, but got confused with this "double connection" thing. I was able to connect to Unix only, but then I don't know how to proceed.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
    session.setPassword(password);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
session.connect();
```

Now that I am connected to Unix, how do I proceed with this step `ftpLogin@hostName :/whatever/.../ $ ftp someftp.example.com`?

I think I might only need to send a command, something like

```
sftpChannel.setCommand("ftpLogin@hostName :/whatever/.../ $ ftp someftp.example.com ?")
```

**How can I connect to a separate FTP from an existing "session/connection"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically use the [local port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding#Local_port_forwarding) for this.

In JSch, after you connect, call the [`setPortForwardingL`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#setPortForwardingL-int-java.lang.String-int-):

```
int ftpPort = session.setPortForwardingL(0, "someftp.example.com", 21);
```

And then connect a local FTP client (e.g. the [`FTPClient` from Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)) to the `localhost:ftpPort`:

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.connect("localhost", ftpPort);
ftp.login("myLogin", password);
```