# How to send UNIX ftp commands using JSch API?

Tags: java, unix, ftp, jsch

I need to send the following `ftp` commands

```
%   ftp test.cs.xxxx.edu  
Connected to test.cs.xxxx.edu.  
220 test FTP server (Version 5.53 ........) ready.  
Name (test.cs.xxxx.edu:yourlogin): yourlogin  
331 Password required for yourlogin.  
Password:  
230 User yourlogin logged in.  
ftp> cd HPSC/exercises  
ftp> get JHFLKDHLFKD.zip
```

---

I tried sending these commands as follows

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();       

Session session_1 = jsch.getSession("user1", "host1", 22); 
session_1.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session_1.setPassword("pass1"); 
session_1.connect();
System.out.println("The session 1  has been established");

ChannelExec exec = (ChannelExec)session_1.openChannel("exec");

exec.connect(); 
exec.setCommand("ftp test.cs.xxxx.edu"); 
exec.setCommand("user2"); 
exec.setCommand("pass2"); 
exec.setCommand("cd \test\test\test"); 
exec.setCommand("get JHFLKDHLFKD.zip");
```

But that did not work. I also tried "shell".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: what do you think interprets the FTP commands when you launch your FTP client? The shell or the FTP client?

Answer (score 0):

The commands you are sending are commands of the `ftp` process. These are not commands the remote shell can understand.

The only real command is the `ftp`. The rest must be fed to the started process to its standard input. Use the [`setInputStream` method](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#setInputStream-java.io.InputStream-) to provide the input.

---

Anyway, you should better use a native FTP client rather that starting a command-line client on the server side, as I've suggested you previously:
[How to connect to an FTP server from an existing connection to Unix server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32721530/850848)

Comment: Thank you. I tried FTP client, but always get `connection refused`,

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an  SFTP client library to communicate with an FTP server.

Despite similar names and purpose, FTP and SFTP are completely different protocols. See 
[Differences between SFTP and "FTP over SSH"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440463/differences-between-sftp-and-ftp-over-ssh)

You need to change either the server or the client, so they match.